# Fourier transformation problem

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-transform

I was practicing Fourier transformations by solving some problems but I wonder if I'm solving problems correct. Could you check my solution, please?

[image]

I tried to calculate the inverse Fourier transform of F(k) I found to verify my solution but the calculations got very complicated...

Comment: Using the result given by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+x*Exp%5B-I*a*x%5D), I find the same  transform : $\frac{1}{k^2\sqrt{2 \pi}}2\left(\cos(k)-k \sin(k)-1 \right)$ **but for the term $1$**.

Comment: @JeanMarie Uhm, assuming the Wolfram Alpha has the correct solution. Could you spot the error in my solution? I checked it over and over again and can't spot an error.

Comment: Sorry, I have spent time on your solution which is difficult to read for me on your photograph (I have not good eyes) and moreover, I must go to bed (very late here in France, and even much later in Turkey !)

Comment: @JeanMarie Uh, sorry tongear that. But still thank you so much for trying. I understand you. Have a good day, sir.